# How to download google docs spreadsheet through R

Tags: r, shiny, google-docs, shiny-server

I would like to download a google docs spreadsheet using R and then import the spreadsheet as a csv file in a small shiny server app.
How could I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [read.csv fails to read a CSV file from google docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834821/read-csv-fails-to-read-a-csv-file-from-google-docs)

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsheet/gsheet.pdf might be helpful

Answer (score 6):

Try the new `googlesheets` package, which is an R API for Google Sheets:

https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

This snippet will install the package, copy a Sheet to your Google Drive, register it for access, and import data from one tab or worksheet into a local data.frame:

```
devtools::install_github("jennybc/googlesheets")
gap_key <- "1HT5B8SgkKqHdqHJmn5xiuaC04Ngb7dG9Tv94004vezA"
copy_ss(key = gap_key, to = "Gapminder")
gap <- register_ss("Gapminder")
oceania_csv <- get_via_csv(gap, ws = "Oceania")
```

As for integration with Shiny, see the `shinyga` package which recently incorporated support for `googlesheets`:

https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/shinyga

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RGoogle Docs package](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/) to access the Google Docs content. Other option worth consider is the [RGoogle Data](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rgoogledata/) package that provides access to Google services.